# Twisted as a client/server problems

Tags: python, client, twisted, block

I'm using twisted to create a "client/server", a programme which act as a client to get some data, and as a server to re-send this data or just to send other data to clients.

I'm using twistd and my code to initialize my factories look like that:

```
application = service.Application('monitorD', uid=0, gid=0)
factoryMonitord = ServerFactory(p)
internet.TCPServer(9000, factoryMonitord).setServiceParent(service.IServiceCollection(application))
#because I need to send some datas from client factory to clients of serverfactory
factoryScamd = ClientFactory(factoryMonitord)
internet.TCPClient("localhost", 8001, factoryScamd).setServiceParent(service.IServiceCollection(application))
```

My problem is when the client part cannot connect (because server is unavaiable), it's look like it "block" all my server part. It's still possible to communicate between my server part and other clients but it's really slow... (and when my client part can be connected it's juste work fine).

Thanks in advance for anyhelp.

EDIT:

Here's my ServerFactory code (a lot of useless code...):

```
class ServerFactory(protocol.ServerFactory):
    protocol = ServerProtocol

    def __init__(self, portal):
        #self.tp = ClientFactory.tp 
        self.tp = []
        self.portal = portal
        self.loop_vol_raid_areca = LoopingCall(self.checkVolRaidAreca)
        self.loop_vol_raid_areca.start(30)
        self.loop_services = LoopingCall(self.checkServices)
        self.loop_services.start(30)

    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        p = protocol.ServerFactory.buildProtocol(self, addr)
        p.portal = self.portal
        return p

    def sendList(self, data):
        if data:
            if isinstance(data, list):
                for element in data:
                    if isinstance(element, list):
                        self.clean_data = "".join(element)
                self.sendToClients(self.clean_data)

    def sendToClients(self, data):
        print "SEND to MonitorC from MonitorD, tp:", self.tp
        if data:
            for tp in self.tp:
                self.protocol.sendLine(tp, data)

    def checkServices(self):
        self.scamd = threads.deferToThread(checkScamd)
        self.scamd.addCallback(self.sendToClients)
        self.httpd = threads.deferToThread(checkHttpd)
        self.httpd.addCallback(self.sendToClients)
        self.postgres = threads.deferToThread(checkPostgres)
        self.postgres.addCallback(self.sendToClients)

    def checkVolRaidAreca(self):
        self.vol = threads.deferToThread(check_vol_areca)
        self.vol.addCallback(self.sendList)
        self.event = threads.deferToThread(get_last_event_areca)
        self.event.addCallback(self.sendList)
```

And here's the client factory with a lot of useless code:

```
class ClientFactory(protocol.ClientFactory):
    protocol = ClientProtocol

    def __init__(self, MonitordFactory):
        self.tp = MonitordFactory.tp

    def clientConnectionFailed(self, connector, reason):
        print "Connection to scamd failed - retrying..."
        time.sleep(30)
        connector.connect()

    def clientConnectionLost(self, connector, reason):
        print "Connection to scamd lost - retrying..."
        time.sleep(30)
        connector.connect()

    def getCamList(self, data):
        cams_list = data.split("\x00")
        self.cams_array = []
        for i in cams_list:
            if str.find(i, "camera") != -1:
                i = i.split(" ")
                i = filter(lambda x: len(x)>0, i)
                self.cams_array.append(i)

    def checkCams(self, data):
        data = data.split(" ")
        for i in self.cams_array:
            if i[1] == data[2]:
                if data[3] == "-1":
                    msg = i[6] + " ERREUR -1"
                if data[3] == "0":
                    msg = i[6] + " ERREUR 0"
                if data[3] == "1":
                    msg = i[6] + " ERREUR 1"
                if data[3] == "2":
                    msg = i[6] + " ERREUR 2 (RECO)"
        return msg
```

If more information needed I will post the entire code to pastebin.
AND, I'm a newbie at python AND twisted (but i used to code in C or C++)

Comment: Can you show us the implementation of your ServerFactory and ClientFactory?

Comment: well of course, without the sleep it's work better, still have sometimes some problems to connect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things you should be able to change right off the bat.  Get rid of the `time.sleep(30)` calls.  Also, you're heavily using the threadpool so you'll likely want to increase the size of it.  Every 30 seconds you're creating 5 threads and because the reactor threadpool size defaults to 5 any other threads you create are going to end up waiting behind those 5.  I'm thinking that having a bunch of queued up threads waiting may be why your service is running more slowly or even appearing to block.

In the short term you may just create your own `twisted.python.threadpool.Threadpool` in your ServerFactory:

```
class ServerFactory(protocol.ServerFactory):
    protocol = ServerProtocol

    def __init__(self, portal):
        # ...
        self.threadpool = ThreadPool(25, 50)

    def checkServices(self):
        # ...
        self.postgres = threads.deferToThreadPool(reactor, self.threadpool, checkPostgres)
```

However, in the long term wherever possible you should look into using an Asynchronous API for dealing with your services.

For example, your `checkHttpd` code could be made asynchronous by using [twisted.web.client.Agent](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/11.0.0/api/twisted.web.client.Agent.html).  For PostgreSQL you can use [txPostgres](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~wulczer/txpostgres/trunk.new/view/head:/txpostgres/txpostgres.py).  I am not familiar with your `scamd` service above so connecting to it with asynchronous IO may be more difficult (i.e.: you may have to write an asynchronous version of the protocol for that service).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't know about the threadpool limitation. Anyway the checkservices are just a kill(pid, 0), just to see if process (or main worker) is here, so i think it's not a problem since it's "light" in term of ressources no?

Comment: You may not even need to use threads for os.kill calls.  Twisted internally considers os.kill to be fast enough to just call directly.

Comment: I tried and yes it works great without os.kill too. thanks for the tip =)

Comment: So is a larger threadpool or just calling os.kill directly improving performance or are you still having problems?